# Use Config.INI file in Azure Synapse Notebook

Tags: python, azure, azure-synapse

I have a on prem code/ python project which I need to move to azure cloud.
Alot of functionality runs around config.**ini** file which contains pre defined variables and their values.

I am not able to use the same config file in Azure synapse, I have kept it in adls gen-2 folder.

```html
import configparser
read_config =configparser.ConfigParser()
config_path = r'https://prodstaticblob.blob.core.windows.net/data/config.ini'
read_config.read(config_path)
list_sections = read_config.sections()
print(list_sections)
```

My output to section list is empty list '[]'

```html
I have tried this path aswell. Am I working with wrong path ?
config_path = r'abfss://data@prodstaticblob.dfs.core.windows.net/config.ini'
```

Connection to that storage location is authorized, I am able to read a sample csv file from same directory. SS below
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `abfss` protocol with spark context only
and the path you need to pass to `configparser` should be from root filesystem.

So, copy the file from adls to local filesystem and read from there.

Below are the content of `config.ini`

[image]

Copy file using `mssparkutils`

```
mssparkutils.fs.cp("abfss://data@jadls2.dfs.core.windows.net/path_to_config.ini","file:/tmp/conf.ini")
```

This will copy the file under `tmp` directory.

```
import configparser
read_config =configparser.ConfigParser()
config_path = "/tmp/conf.ini"
read_config.read(config_path)
list_sections = read_config.sections()
print(list_sections)
print(read_config.get("Database","db_host"))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hey Jayashankar, thanks for your reply, Let me try this approach. I have been working on AWS before this and there its pretty straight forward.  1 question, is it possible to download from  this location. file:/tmp/conf.ini' ?? How do you see / edit the config file. I need to give permission to client / user to view / edit this config file .

Comment: `/tmp/conf.ini` is temporary path for copying the file. If you want to download you can download it from storage account directly right?

Comment: can you paste a screenshot how you find this path location. I am struggling with it. @JayashankarGS

Comment: `file:/tmp/config.ini` ? Run
`%sh ls /tmp/`. In new separate cell.

Comment: Thanks brother. really helpfull. Marked your reply as answer. Do you have any documentation link to this approach as well. Somehow I am not able to find it myself. Thanks again.